# Get Message ID in response of send mail - SendGrid API v3

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am getting this response when I submit an email, as I am working on the API of SendGrid I need to grab the stats of each mail i sent.. for that purpose I want the Message-ID in response so I could save that in db.. I have looked over the docs but unable to make any progress.. Thanks in Advance

But i want to get email activity by passing message ID
Note: Currently mail response give "X-Message-ID" but i want Message ID

https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-messages-by-message-id

Thanks...

Comment: did u get the id in response? pls let me know how to do it ? thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The `X-` prefix in a header means that it is a custom header and not part of the standard.  This has become less favoured over time, but it is still found in use across the internet. `X-Message-Id` is what you're looking for.